# Header and footer are getting shorter than the body

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

[![

```js
const navBtn = document.querySelector(".nav-toggle");
const showLinks = document.querySelector(".show-links");
const links = document.querySelector(".links");

navBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
   links.classList.toggle("show-links");
})
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Lemonada', cursive, sans-serif;
}
header {
    background:black;
  
  
    width:100%;
    z-index: 999;
}
img {
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 70px;
}

.center {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding:.87rem;
}
.nav-toggle{
    border-color: transparent;
    font-size:1.5rem;
    background:rgb(238, 242, 15);
    cursor: pointer;
    color:black;
    transition:all 300ms ease-in;
}
.nav-toggle:hover{
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    color:rgb(153, 156, 5);
}
.links{
 
    list-style-type: none;
    
}

.links a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color:floralwhite;
    letter-spacing:0.25rem;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    transition:all 300ms ease-in;
}
.links a:hover {
    background:rgb(28, 28, 12);
    color:#49a6e9;
    padding-left:1.5rem;
}
.links {
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition:all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.show-links {
    height: 9rem;
}

#home {
    border: 8px ridge green;
    max-width:100%;
    margin:1rem;
    padding:1rem;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

#about > iframe{
   
    width:95%;
    margin:.87rem;
  
}
#contact{
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:1rem;

}
#submit{
    border-color: transparent;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding:0.6rem;
    background:rgb(168, 168, 45);
    color:black;
    font-size:1.4rem;
    border-radius: 20%;
    cursor:pointer;
    box-shadow:2px 2px rgb(135, 135, 38);
    position: relative;
    margin:1rem;
    display: block;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:1rem;
    margin-bottom:0.75rem;
}
#submit:active{
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgb(168, 168, 45);
    transform:translate(2px, 2px);
}
#email{
    display: block;
    width:94%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:1rem;
}
.footer{
    background: black;
    width:100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
.links-footer{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    
}
.links-footer a{
    color:floralwhite;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    letter-spacing:0.25rem;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    line-height: 5;
    align-items:flex-end;
}

.address{


    color:floralwhite;
    line-height: 3  ;
    font-size:0.85rem;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px){
.nav-toggle{
    display:none;
    }
    #nav-bar{
        display:flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        
    }
    .links{
        display: flex;
        font-size:1.4rem;
        align-items: center;
        height: auto;
    }
    .links a:hover{
        padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
        color:rgb(165, 213, 248);
        background: black;
    }
    #home{
        max-width:50%;
        margin:0 auto;
        margin-top:1rem;
    }
    #about > iframe{
   
        max-width:50%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        margin:0 auto;
        margin-top:1rem;
      
    }
    #email{
        display: block;
        width:50%;
        margin:0 auto;
        padding:1rem;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lemonada&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="product.css">
    <title>Product Land Page</title>
</head>
<body>
 <header id="header">
     <nav id="nav-bar">
         <div class="center">
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="" id="header-img">
            <button class="nav-toggle">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
        </div>

        <ul class="links ">
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#home">home</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#about">about us</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#contact">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
     </nav>

 </header>
 <div id="home">
     <p>
        A beehive is an enclosed, man-made structure in which some honey bee species of the subgenus Apis live and raise their young. 
        Though the word beehive is commonly used to describe the nest of any bee colony, scientific and professional literature distinguishes nest from hive. 
        Nest is used to discuss colonies which house themselves in natural or artificial cavities or are hanging and exposed. 
        Hive is used to describe an artificial, man-made structure to house a honey bee nest.
     </p>
 </div>
 <div id="about">
    <iframe  id="video" height="365"    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RewbGiiBFd4" frameborder="0" 
    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>
 <div id="contact">
     <form action=" https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit" id="form">
         <input type="email" id="email" required placeholder="Enter your e-mail address">
         <input type="submit" id="submit">
     </form>
 </div>
 <footer class="footer">
     <div class="links-footer">
        <ul class=" ">
            <li><a class="" href="#home">home</a></li>
            <li><a class="" href="#about">about us</a></li>
            <li><a class="" href="#contact">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="address">
        <h4>Our Address</h4>
        <address>
          121, Clear Water Bay Road<br>
          Clear Water Bay, Kowloon<br>
          HONG KONG<br>
         <i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg"></i>: +852 1234 5678<br>
          <i class="fa fa-fax fa-lg"></i>: +852 8765 4321<br>
          
       </address>
    </div>

 </footer>
 <script src="product.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKlVh.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKlVh.png)

hi the problem i don't know how i can explain but,  when i am getting smaller the page size using chrome developper tools, checking for responsive design. if you change the view size under the 450px, also appear white color next to the footer and the header which they have got black color.anyone knows why this occur ?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I think you should give body an explicit width.
I know you have given your header and footer a 100 percent width but what 100% width does is make the element's content area exactly equal to the explicit width of its parent — **but only if its parent has an explicit width**.

Comment: i gave the body width:100% and also max-width:100% it is the same didnt change.the problem still exist.

Answer (score 1):

Replace This CSS like

```
#about > iframe {
        width: calc(100% - 1.74rem);
        margin:.87rem;
    }
```

```js
const navBtn = document.querySelector(".nav-toggle");
const showLinks = document.querySelector(".show-links");
const links = document.querySelector(".links");

navBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
   links.classList.toggle("show-links");
})
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Lemonada', cursive, sans-serif;
}
header {
    background:black;
  
  
    width:100%;
    z-index: 999;
}
img {
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 70px;
}

.center {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding:.87rem;
}
.nav-toggle{
    border-color: transparent;
    font-size:1.5rem;
    background:rgb(238, 242, 15);
    cursor: pointer;
    color:black;
    transition:all 300ms ease-in;
}
.nav-toggle:hover{
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    color:rgb(153, 156, 5);
}
.links{
 
    list-style-type: none;
    
}

.links a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color:floralwhite;
    letter-spacing:0.25rem;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    transition:all 300ms ease-in;
}
.links a:hover {
    background:rgb(28, 28, 12);
    color:#49a6e9;
    padding-left:1.5rem;
}
.links {
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition:all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.show-links {
    height: 9rem;
}

#home {
    border: 8px ridge green;
    max-width:100%;
    margin:1rem;
    padding:1rem;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

#about > iframe {
    width: calc(100% - 1.74rem);
    margin:.87rem;
}
#contact{
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:1rem;

}
#submit{
    border-color: transparent;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding:0.6rem;
    background:rgb(168, 168, 45);
    color:black;
    font-size:1.4rem;
    border-radius: 20%;
    cursor:pointer;
    box-shadow:2px 2px rgb(135, 135, 38);
    position: relative;
    margin:1rem;
    display: block;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:1rem;
    margin-bottom:0.75rem;
}
#submit:active{
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgb(168, 168, 45);
    transform:translate(2px, 2px);
}
#email{
    display: block;
    width:94%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:1rem;
}
.footer{
    background: black;
    width:100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
.links-footer{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    
}
.links-footer a{
    color:floralwhite;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    letter-spacing:0.25rem;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    line-height: 5;
    align-items:flex-end;
}

.address{


    color:floralwhite;
    line-height: 3  ;
    font-size:0.85rem;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px){
.nav-toggle{
    display:none;
    }
    #nav-bar{
        display:flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        
    }
    .links{
        display: flex;
        font-size:1.4rem;
        align-items: center;
        height: auto;
    }
    .links a:hover{
        padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
        color:rgb(165, 213, 248);
        background: black;
    }
    #home{
        max-width:50%;
        margin:0 auto;
        margin-top:1rem;
    }
    #about > iframe{
   
        max-width:50%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        margin:0 auto;
        margin-top:1rem;
      
    }
    #email{
        display: block;
        width:50%;
        margin:0 auto;
        padding:1rem;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lemonada&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="product.css">
    <title>Product Land Page</title>
</head>
<body>
 <header id="header">
     <nav id="nav-bar">
         <div class="center">
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="" id="header-img">
            <button class="nav-toggle">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
        </div>

        <ul class="links ">
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#home">home</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#about">about us</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#contact">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
     </nav>

 </header>
 <div id="home">
     <p>
        A beehive is an enclosed, man-made structure in which some honey bee species of the subgenus Apis live and raise their young. 
        Though the word beehive is commonly used to describe the nest of any bee colony, scientific and professional literature distinguishes nest from hive. 
        Nest is used to discuss colonies which house themselves in natural or artificial cavities or are hanging and exposed. 
        Hive is used to describe an artificial, man-made structure to house a honey bee nest.
     </p>
 </div>
 <div id="about">
    <iframe  id="video" height="365"    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RewbGiiBFd4" frameborder="0" 
    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>
 <div id="contact">
     <form action=" https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit" id="form">
         <input type="email" id="email" required placeholder="Enter your e-mail address">
         <input type="submit" id="submit">
     </form>
 </div>
 <footer class="footer">
     <div class="links-footer">
        <ul class=" ">
            <li><a class="" href="#home">home</a></li>
            <li><a class="" href="#about">about us</a></li>
            <li><a class="" href="#contact">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="address">
        <h4>Our Address</h4>
        <address>
          121, Clear Water Bay Road<br>
          Clear Water Bay, Kowloon<br>
          HONG KONG<br>
         <i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg"></i>: +852 1234 5678<br>
          <i class="fa fa-fax fa-lg"></i>: +852 8765 4321<br>
          
       </address>
    </div>

 </footer>
 <script src="product.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks it is working until 190px width. from this point the header and footer are smaller than the view of page.